# "nice" for Networking

Tags: command-line, networking

UNIXish systems have a command-line utility called `nice` that can be used to run programs at a low priority, so that they don't hog the CPU.

Is there anything analogous that will limit the amount of network bandwidth a program uses?  Sometimes I'd like to start a big download, but want my web browsing and other interactive network usage to stay responsive.

---

Related questions:

- [Bandwidth Throttle for linux](https://superuser.com/questions/32265/bandwidth-throttle-for-linux)
- [Throttle network bandwidth per application in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/126642/throttle-network-bandwidth-per-application-in-mac-os-x)
- [How can I make bandwidth intensive applications have lower priority than other apps like web browsing/skype](https://superuser.com/questions/74744/how-can-i-make-bandwidth-intensive-applications-have-lower-priority-than-other-ap)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`trickle -d 10 command` runs *command*, limiting its bandwidth to 10kB/s. This is the analog of `nice` for bandwidth. It is packaged by at least Debian and Ubuntu.

[`ip_relay`](http://www.stewart.com.au/ip_relay/) and [`redir`](http://sammy.net/~sammy/hacks/) are both tiny TCP proxies that support bandwidth limiting. Neither of them seem to have been maintained recently, but they're packaged by at least Debian and Ubuntu.

But maybe the tool you're using for downloading already supports bandwidth limitation, for instance `wget --limit-rate=10k`, `curl --limit-rate 10k`, `rsync --bwlimit=10`.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this twice.

Comment: made a point to login just so I could upvote this answer. trickle is great!

Comment: These are not the analog of `nice` (though they are very useful!). `nice` defines a priority, not a limit. An analog of `nice` would give a process unlimited bandwidth if no other process wanted it.

Comment: If you want a priority, try configuring QoS in your router.